# How do I mount the EFI partition on Windows 8.1 so that it is readable and writeable?

Tags: windows-8, efi

Here is what I do:

1. restart machine with Windows 8.1
2. determine "EFI System" partition with the Disk Management utility
3. run command prompt as administrator
4. type `diskpart`
5. type `select disk 0` then `select partition 2` then `assign`
6. open windows explorer `windows+e`
7. refresh if the drive is not showing `F5`
8. try to open drive by double clicking

What I expected to happen:

I can at least look at my EFI partition files.

What happened:

[image: after double clicking]

after clicking continue

[image: after clicking continue]

after clicking "security tab" link, no security tab

[image: after clicking security tab, no security tab]

What do I need to do to access my EFI partition on Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way I found is to open it in the administrator command prompt:

type `E:`
then you can browse around and edit the files

Comment: Yeah, if magic is real, this is it. you can use XCOPY command to transfer

Answer (score 49):

The [official way](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mountvol) of mounting the EFI partition is

```
mountvol b: /s
```

where `b:` is a drive letter of your choosing. You can remove the mapping with:

```
mountvol b: /d
```

You still need to launch `explorer.exe` with administrative privileges in order to see the mountpoint (kill `explorer.exe`, then launch one from an elevated command prompt)

Comment: Or using another file manager: https://freecommander.com/en/summary/ then running it as administrator.

Answer (score 37):

The reason why you can't access it on Windows Explorer (File Explorer) is because by default it does not run with administrative privileges. If you let's say kill Explorer and execute it again from an elevated command prompt then you will have access to the EFI partition through File Explorer.

First open an elevated command prompt and give the EFI partition a drive letter, you can do it with `mountvol` as shown in [jmiserez's answer](https://superuser.com/a/735400) (recommended) or with `diskpart`. In the following example the EFI partition is on `disk 0`, `partition 1` and will be assigned to letter `b`:

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk 0
list partition
select partition 1
assign letter=b
exit
```

Now kill the File Explorer process and start it with administrative privileges:

```
taskkill /im explorer.exe /f
explorer.exe
```

Now you can access the EFI partition with File Explorer.

[image]

Note that the EFI partition is a FAT32 file system partition. FAT partitions don't have the *Security* tab, this is a NTFS feature only.

Comment: I'm curious, why does it matter? Explorer seems fine accessing other folders with only admin rights, like `system volume information`.

Comment: I am using a limited user account. Killing `explorer.exe` and starting it from the elevated command prompt resulted in a dysfunctional GUI, with only a start button, without any desktop, icons, or any way of using file explorer. Looks like this has to be done in a real admin account.

Comment: @MilindR, Go to `%windir%` find for `explorer.exe`, right click that and run as administrator.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Windows 10, after launching explorer as admin it still said that I don't have permissions :(

Comment: @szx A way I've found convenient to quickly browse the files on the EFI partition is to open an app such as Notepad as administrator, then use the Open file dialog.

Comment: after killing explorer type `explorer.exe /nouaccheck`. works for me win10

Answer (score 4):

I tried everything and nothing worked on explorer for me.
I tried killing and running explorer from elevated cmd, and also tried the same with PowerShell and nothing worked.
I could however edit inside cmd and powershell but not GUI/Explorer.

It is very odd but if you Download [Explorer++](https://explorerplusplus.com/) it works.
 Extract it and **run as admin**

[From this post:-](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/311820-guide-mount-and-access-efi-partition-on-windows-10/)

It took me some time to find a workaround so I thought I share it.

1- **Mount the EFI partition to a free mount point:**
-- Run command prompt as administrator
-- Type "mountvol X: /s" (without the quotes, X being an unused mount point)

2- **Use Explorer++** (Free, Open Source app) to manipulate the files on the partition:
-- Run Explorer++ with administrative privileges

Hope you find this useful

Comment: I should mention, that any file manager (Total Commander, Double Commander, FAR etc.) that can be explicitly run with admin privileges would handle opening EFI partition.

Comment: as of this date, this doesn't work

Comment: As of this date, this DOES work.

Answer (score 0):

Press **Start** and type `gpedit.msc` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
This will open your Group Policy Editor.

Expand **Administrative Templates**

[image]

Expand **Windows Components** -> **File Explorer**

[image]

Locate **Remove Security tab** in the right pane and double click to open

[image]

Select the **Disabled** radio button and press **OK**

Now check for your security tab :)

[image]

Now, you can add yourself Read/Write permissions or just take the ownership

Comment: My installation of Windows does not seem to have the command gpedit.msc, I think it might be because I am not running Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: -1 FAT32 does not have security.