# Boot manager not picking up correct EFI

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot

So I'm trying to dual boot between windows and ubuntu. I think I got everything set up Ubuntu wise, but I can't seem to boot into it. I used the following:
[How do I mount the EFI partition on Windows 8.1 so that it is readable and writeable?](https://superuser.com/questions/662823/how-do-i-mount-the-efi-partition-on-windows-8-1-so-that-it-is-readable-and-write)
To see whether or not ubuntu was added into the EFI and it looks like it was. I then tried the following:
http://linux.about.com/od/LinuxNewbieDesktopGuide/tp/3-Ways-To-Fix-The-UEFI-Bootloader-When-Dual-Booting-Windows-And-Ubuntu.htm
In order to get the boot loading properly, but it still wont run. All the files seem to be there, and bcdedit is showing the correct infrmation, so not sure what is wrong. Here is the bcdedit:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>bcdedit

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {xxxxxxxx-acf9-11e2-8b80-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 8.1
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {xxxxxxxx-acf9-11e2-8b80-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {xxxxxxxx-acf9-11e2-8b80-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
```

I've tried the following three .efi settings, and all three seem to not work:

```
\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi
```

(Here's the install guide for refind: http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#windows)

I'm using windows8.1 and oddly noticed that in the EFI I have my computer manufacturer in there as well (MSI). I'm sure that's fairly standard, but figured I'd mention it just in case that alters anything.

Any help would be beneficial as I'm confused as to why boot manager points to the correct efi path, but still isn't managing to grab that path.

(Note that I do have 'fast boot' turned off in windows as I know that causes some issues during booting)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a knowledgebase article from EasyBCD that may help:

https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/dual-boot/linux/ubuntu

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
Please take a look here: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://superuser.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Additionally, the article you provided only gives information as to how to make 3rd party software fix the issue. I know that EasyBCD exists, but I'd much prefer to learn why the methods I'm using by hand aren't working rather than using some software without understanding the core underlying issues.