# Mounting EFI partition on Windows

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, partitioning, efi, disk-management

I'm trying to mount the EFI Partition from `Disk Management` but all the options for the EFI partition are greyed out, so I can't do anything..

here's a screenshot from the problem :

[image: Here's a screenshot from the EFI partition options greyed out!]

Comment: use a Win CLI based prog like DISM, DiskPart, MountVol, etc...

Comment: @BiTinerary Already did with MountVol, I get *** NO MOUNT POINTS ***.

Comment: What OS is on the drive? Internal or External drive? Try the first answer from this one >> http://superuser.com/questions/662823/how-do-i-mount-the-efi-partition-on-windows-8-1-so-that-it-is-readable-and-write?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Windows 7:

1. Locate Command Prompt in the Start menu, right-click it, and select "Run as Administrator."
2. Type `mountvol P: /S` in the Administrator Command Prompt window. This makes the ESP accessible as drive P: from that window. (You can change the drive identifier if you like.)

Note that this will not make the drive accessible in the GUI. Also, I'm not sure offhand how to open the Administrator Command Prompt window if you're using Windows 8 or later.