# The directory is not empty when using mountvol to mount efi partition

Tags: windows, windows-10, mount, efi, boot-partition

I followed the answers to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/662823/how-do-i-mount-the-efi-partition-on-windows-8-1-so-that-it-is-readable-and-write) question but none of them seem to work. When I use `mountvol E: /s` I get the error "The directory is not empty" even though it is empty and I've formatted it multiple times. When I create a folder named efi inside E: and run `mountvol E:\efi /s` I get the parameter is incorrect. I was able to mount using the diskpart method, however, I still cannot access the partition through explorer as it does not open with elevated privileges. I tried the task kill method from the previous question along with creating a new task with elevated privileges using task manager but both of the methods opened explorer with normal privileges and I get the same error as the question linked above of not having permission. I'm using windows 10. I have searched everywhere but haven't found any solution.